# Querying MySQL tables and displaying results in tabbed-panes

Tags: php, javascript

I have an PHP array. I have to loop over it to query 3 MySQL tables. The attributes of all the tables are the same, just the table names are different.

Once I get the results I have to display it in tabbed-panes. I will have 3 tabbed-panes. When I click on the tab, respective results should populate the table.

How can I go about retrieving and displaying this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Tabs widget in jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

There are several approaches for populating the tabs with data. The easiest one is to use PHP to to generate HTML similar to this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Tab 1 content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Tab 2 content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Tab 3 content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Replace data inside the "tabs-x" div tags with output from your database query.

Javascript for initializing the tabs:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

If you need the tabs to populate when clicked, take a look at the AJAX-option: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax

Comment: I am very new to javascript. How do I load this once my MySQL querying is done?

Comment: jQuery has a ready event which you can use to execute javascript once the page is loaded: http://api.jquery.com/ready/ The code in my example works this way. Just insert it in head inside a normal script tag, and the tabs-call will execute after the page is loaded. Remember to include the jQuery and jQuery UI scripts before the script tag.